# How much does strings affect binary size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

> Keep Data out of Code
>
> Moving any resources, such as long strings, or tables, out of code and
>   into external files will make the final download smaller, because
>   external files compress more efficiently than when the data is
>   compiled into a binary. See iOS App Store Specific Considerations for
>   full technical background.

How much does strings affect binary size in iOS apps, being in code versus their own file?

Is this something significant? Right now my binary size from code is 4mb, but it has a lot of long texts. How much can it decrease?

Comment: Why don't you test it your self saving all strings to disk?

Comment: I tried, but for reason my machine doesn't compile the exact same binary size even if I don't change anything in the project.

Comment: Not enough to matter; your binary at 4MB is already tiny and savings are likely marginal.  Incidentally I have a feeling using localized strings may actually make it slightly bigger because now you need the localized string and the key in both the binary and the string table.  In any case it doesn't matter because the strings are so much smaller than the images and other assets.  You would probably save more space by swapping out one png file with a vector than you would from removing all of the strings from your app.

Comment: @JoshHomann If you put a vector PDF in image assets, building turns the PDF into pngs for each resolution and it will still ship pngs.  But, Xcode's generation might be smaller than whatever you might do.

Comment: There are other reasons to keep strings separately (for example: translation or ease of editing by non Xcode users).

Comment: @LouFranco yes. by replacing png with a vector I mean something like using svgkit or paintcode (which is the way I do it) and not using the asset catalog.  I primarily do this for flexibility with respect to resizing and recoloring and not because of file size though.